# How to change permissions on output flushed to browser?

Tags: php, excel

I'm creating an Excel file using PHP. PHP creates the file, but the files' permissions are set to 'read only'. I'd like to have permissions that allow the user to edit the file. I am not creating a new file on the server (I'd like to reserve that option if everything else fails).

Here's the relevant code:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename ");     
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

$out = ob_get_clean();
echo $out;
xlsEOF();
exit();
```

Comment: You have three content-type headers, but you can only have one (which should be `application/vnd.ms-excel` for an Excel document).

Comment: Well spotted Quentin, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a real problem.

In Linux, the user that downloads the file has permissions to edit the file but others only have 'read only' permissions (see attached image).

I was incorrectly assuming that Windows users would also see a 'read only' attribute, so the 'problem' is as a result of a false premise.[image: the red asterisks on the image show the file permissions. I was incorrectly assuming the 'read only' attribute would be associated files in Windows as well]

Comment: Yea, it's just a normal permissions thing on the client-side. Nothing to do with PHP or HTTP.